# How to give superuser rights in postgres

Tags: postgresql, devops

Log volume kata gives this error. They are related to postgres. That the uuid-ossp extension cannot be created. Only the superuser can create it. To fix it, I log in as the postgres user in psql, give the superuser flsh user and get the error: postg

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like `postgres` is not a superuser in your installation so the hint does not apply. Log in as `odoo_user` instead.

Comment: If you are installing that extension to get a function to generate UUIDs, this is no longer necessary since Postgres 13: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html